# Why is this Perl CGI Program not calculating items in hash array?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, cgi

I wrote a program that allows users to pick the size of the product and put the sizes in a hash array. However, when I try to code the part where it adds up all the toppings listed (the user can pick multiple toppings but just 1 size), my formula is not working.

```
my %size = ('Regular' => 6.00,
        'Large' => 8.00,
        'Family' => 11.00);

my $size = param('size');

my @toppings = param('toppings');

my $total_topping = $toppings * 1.25;
my $total = $size + $total_topping;
print ('Total Due: $total');
```

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings;`! You use a variable named `$toppings`, but you never (declared or) assigned a value to such a variable.

Comment: Also, the fact that `%size` isn't used is suggests the presence of a second problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other have mentioned, you should alway include `use strict` and `use warnings` in your code. That would point out some of your problems.

Let's look at your code.

```
# This defines a hash mapping sizes of pizza to price
my %size = ('Regular' => 6.00,
        'Large' => 8.00,
        'Family' => 11.00);

# And this gets the size parameter from the user's request.
# Presumably, this value should be one of the keys from the %size hash.
my $size = param('size');

# This gets an array of all of the toppings the user has selected.
my @toppings = param('toppings');

# Each topping adds £1.25 to the price, so to get the total price
# for toppings, we need to multiply the number of toppings by 1.25.
# But that's not what you're doing here. You're using a new scalar 
# variable called $toppings. This will be undef and will therefore
# be interpreted as zero.
# This problem would have been picked up by "use strict"
my $total_topping = $toppings * 1.25;

# And here you're adding $size to $total_toppings to get the
# total price of the pizza. But $size doesn't contain the price,
# it contains the description of the size. Any of your sizes will
# be interpreted as 0 when used as a number. So $total will end
# up as 0 + 0 = 0.
# This problem would have been picked up by "use warnings".
my $total = $size + $total_topping;
print ('Total Due: $total');
```

So, you had two errors:

1. You used `$toppings` instead of `@toppings` to get the number of toppings.
2. You forgot to translate the size name to the size price.

Your code should look more like this:

```
my %size = (Regular => 6.00,
            Large   => 8.00,
            Family  => 11.00);

my $size = param{'size');
# Check for valid size
if (! exists $size{$size}) {
  die "$size is not a valid size of pizza";
}
# Convert name of size to cost of size.
my $size_cost = $size{$size};

my @toppings = param('toppings');

# Array in scalar context gives number of elements
my $total_toppings = @toppings * 1.25;

my $total = $size_cost + $total_topping;
print ('Total Due: $total');
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined a hash `%size` but never use it? Where are the values of $toppings?

Anyway, see here is a way to display the value of the key 'Large' just to give an idea on how to use hash.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %size = (Regular  => "6",
            Large => "8",
            Family  => "11",
           );

print $size{Large};
```

You can also assign the keys to an array

```
my @Sizes = keys %size;
```